# Why can't see enum-type index in explain query?

Tags: sql, postgresql, indexing, enums

I'm trying to add index that is enum-type field (status), but can't see any `index scan` for that index in explain query. Couldn't get the point that I'm missing.

```
-- t_post_status = ('waiting', 'published', 'deleted')

create index status ON public."Post" USING btree ((status::t_post_status))
```

So, when I run the queries below, I got the result following;

```
explain select id from "Post" where status = 'published' limit 1
explain select id from "Post" where status = 'published'::t_post_status limit 1

Limit  (cost=0.00..0.20 rows=1 width=4)
  ->  Seq Scan on "Post"  (cost=0.00..5692.64 rows=29192 width=4)
        Filter: (status = 'published'::t_post_status)
```

But, when these, I can see `index scan` for id (or and other index when I change the query);

```
explain select id from "Post" where status = 'published' and id = 1 limit 1
explain select id from "Post" where status = 'published'::t_post_status and id = 1 limit 1

Limit  (cost=0.29..8.31 rows=1 width=4)
  ->  Index Scan using "Post_pkey" on "Post"  (cost=0.29..8.31 rows=1 width=4)
        Index Cond: (id = 1)
        Filter: (status = 'published'::t_post_status)
```

Comment: What's the distribution of the three values? is it like 33% + 33% + 33% or more like 98% + 1% + 1%?

Comment: @TheImpaler I just wrote only tree values, but there are more.

Comment: If using PostgreSQL 10+, please do: `analyze public."Post"`. Then post the result from: `select * from pg_stats where tablename = 'Post' and attname = 'status'`.

Comment: Yes, the query plan says there are around 29 thousand rows. The question is: are the status evenly distributed, or most of the rows have the same status?

Comment: @TheImpaler The result of `analyze public."Post"`: `Query returned successfully with no result in 2.4 secs.`

Comment: @TheImpaler Most of the statuses are `published`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the value `published` is so "popular" in the table, it seems PostgreSQL's SQL optimizer decided that is cheaper to use a sequential table scan, than using the index.

Why? Because a single read of the heap will most likely find a row with that value (due to its omnipresence). It will rarely need a second I/O operation to read a second heap block.

The alternative option of using the index (the one you expected) would require:

- An index walk.
- Then a single heap read.

This is most likely more expensive than hitting the heap at once.

Pretty clever.

Comment: Yes! When I change it as `status = 'waiting'` I can see that result: `Index Cond: (status = 'waiting')`. BUT, adding another field with `AND` keyword, eg: `status = 'waiting' and id = 1`, causing to skip `status` index again. Clever, but also some weird. :)
Thank you by the way.